# IIS 6.0 Application pool crash

Tags: iis-6, application-pools

One application pool on one of our webservers crashed and we found this in the Eventlog, where can we find more information about it?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1101
Date:       11/23/2009
Time:       10:57:55 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ID-WEB
Description:
The World Wide Web Publishing Service failed to create app pool 'Global'.  The data field contains the error number.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: b7 00 07 80               ·..
```

Attempting to manually start the application pool gives the following in the event log:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1107
Date:       11/23/2009
Time:       3:53:13 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ID-WEB
Description:
The World Wide Web Publishing Service failed to modify app pool 'Global'.  The data field contains the error number.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 05 40 00 80               .@.
```

We are running IIS 6.0 on a Windows server 2003 R2, 32bits.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the events for application pool crashes in the event log do not give much information. Your going to want to run a tool such as [IIS Debug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919790), which will run on your server and wait for a crash to happen and log debug information about what occured.

Answer (score 0):

App Pool crashes are usually because the AppPool Identity isn't a member of the IIS_WPG local security group...  Additionally, the AppPool identity must have read access to the web content that is being displayed...